# C# Array Merge Without Duplicates

Tags: c#

Let's say I have these two arrays:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[2]{"Hello", "Stack"}
string[] arr2 = new string[2]{"Stack", "Overflow"}
```

How would I merge them to get a third array like so: `string[2]{"Hello", "Overflow"}`?

Comment: arr1.Concat(arr2).Distinct()

Comment: What attempt have you made? Also what is the question? I am not sure how you make the 3rd array at all

Comment: I assume you mean: `string[3]{"Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"}`?

Comment: Assuming you meant to include "Stack" in the output: `arr1.Union(arr2)`.

Comment: Or if you really need to exclude anything that is duplicated, `arr1.Except(arr2).Union(arr2.Except(arr1))`

Comment: be aware of case-sensitivity `Stack` != `stack`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = arr1
  .Concat(arr2)
  .GroupBy(item => item)  
  .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
  .Select(group => group.Key)
  .ToArray();
```

Here we

1. `Concat` arrays to get `{Hello, Stack, Stack, Overflow}`
2. `GroupBy` items to have `{{Hello}, {Stack, Stack}, {Overflow}}` groups
3. Filter to have groups with 1 item only: `{Hello}, {Overflow}`
4. Materialize groups to `{Hello, Overflow}` array

Comment: well you did produce the expected result, but I doubt it is actually what OP wants and it is maybe a typo

Comment: @RandRandom I don't think OP actually made typo - the title explicitly calls "without duplicates" and samples shows union with duplicates removed... Now this answer only works for sample shown in the question (which is still better than other answers that flat out answer something else and clearly duplicate of existing posts), but does not actually compute Union - Intersection (sample: ["bob", "bob"] and ["top"]). Indeed OP could clarify if initial arrays are actually sets - this answer could benefit from such clarification (could be done in the answer too)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - maybe though it seems we may never know, OP is silent - I didn't  understand the part `... but does not actually compute Union - Intersection ...` seems correct to me https://dotnetfiddle.net/9do4cC

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=net-7.0) method. This code gives what you want:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[2] { "Hello", "Stack" };
string[] arr2 = new string[2] { "Stack", "Overflow" };

HashSet<string> set1 = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
HashSet<string> set2 = new HashSet<string>(arr2);

set1.SymmetricExceptWith(set2);
string[] arr3 = set1.ToArray();
// Here arr3 is { "Hello", "Overflow" }
```

For more details have a look at [Symmetric Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to use the Concat, distinct, and toarray methods. Like this:

```
string[] arr3 = arr1.Concat(arr2).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: `Union(arr2)` is shorter than `Concat(arr2).Distinct()`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko And your answer with half a screen worth of code is better than this one-liner?

Comment: @MikeBruno indeed Dmitry's answer better as it produces result that at least on the given input produces expected result... Unlike this one which does not provide desired input even for the case shown in the question. (Nor calls out what the answer actually answers if author of the answer consider "expected" in the question to be typo)